# chmod +x: affect file in one OS or all OSes

Tags: chmod

For example, I have a file named `run.sh`. I want to make this file executable, so I run:

```
chmod +x run.sh
```

My question is:

- This command makes this file executable. So if I bring this file to different OS, will it still executable ?
- If is still executable, so why don't people make it executable before sending somewhere else ?

I ask this, because as I tested on Docker environment, I see that: I make file executable on host environment will be affected on docker environment.

Thanks

Comment: I may be wrong but I think, it depends how you transfer it. If you transfer a file using a device (like a USB stick) it depends what filesystem it supports. Some filesystems do not save permissions. Also I'd guess that it's a good security measure, if you download an executable file, you have to turn it executable yourself, so you don't accidentally run it.

Comment: So. In one special case, for example. transfer between two same OS. but totally different machine ?

Answer (score 2):

Files' permissions are kept on disk, so when you set a file's executable bit, that is stored on the disk.  If you "bring the file to another OS" by moving the disk or just booting a different OS, the metadata for the file will be the same.

However, if you, by "bring", mean some operation such as `scp` or some other file transfer mechanism, these typically do *not* by default carry along metadata such as modify times or permissions.  You can do this with e. g. `scp -p`.  From the manual:

```
 -p      Preserves modification times, access times, and modes from the original file.
```

"modes" here are what are commonly referred to as permissions (indeed, `chmod` is short for "change mode", after all).  Presuming that the filesystem at the destination for the copy operation knows what do do with these metadata, it would still have the same permissions on the new host.

Answer (score 0):

> So if I bring this file to different OS, will it still executable ?

It will depend on the manner of bringing (i.e. bringing FS on remote storage doesn't support execute flag).

> If is still executable, so why don't people make it executable before
>   sending somewhere else ?

Maybe some people knows its behaviour and thus donesn't do bringing in that manner.